# required argument directoryList in parent::__construct call

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.5, construct

I'm getting this error but I don't really understand it.. as I'm looking through the file I believe the error is complaining about this bit of code. Is it missing the path to a directory or something?

**Updated**
Below is my file

```
<?php
/**
 * This module is used to move import file to archive folder
 *
 * @category: PHP
 * @package: Perficient_ImportExport
 * @copyright: Copyright © 2021 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * @license: Magento Enterprise Edition (MEE) license
 * @keywords: Perficient Import Export
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Perficient\ImportExport\Model\Job\Handler;

use Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Job\Handler\CompressHandler as FireBearCompressHandler;
use Firebear\ImportExport\Api\Data\ImportInterface;
use Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Job\Processor;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use ZipArchive as Archive;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


/**
 * Class CompressHandler
 * This class is used to move import file to archive folder
 */
class CompressHandler extends FireBearCompressHandler
{
    /**
     * @var Processor
     */
    private $processor;

    /**
     * @var Archive
     */
    private $archive;

    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $timeZone;

    /**
     * CompressHandler constructor.
     * @param Processor $processor
     * @param Archive $archive
     * @param TimezoneInterface $timezone
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        Processor $processor,
        Archive $archive,
        TimezoneInterface $timezone
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $directoryList,
            $processor,
            $archive,
            $timezone
        );
        $this->processor = $processor;
        $this->archive = $archive;
        $this->timeZone = $timezone;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the handler
     *
     * @param ImportInterface $job
     * @param string $file
     * @param int $status
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(ImportInterface $job, $file, $status)
    {
        $data = $job->getSourceData();
        if (!empty($data['archive_file_after_import'])) {
            $import = $this->processor->getImportModel();
            $platform = $import->getPlatform($data['platforms'] ?? null, $job->getEntity());
            $isGateway = $platform && $platform->isGateway();
            if (!$isGateway) {
                //if ($import->getSource()->isRemote()) {
                    $path = $import->getSource()->getTempFilePath();
                    if ($this->compress($path)) {
                        /* remove uploaded temp file */
                        $import->getSource()->resetSource();
                    }
                //}
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compress file
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    private function compress($path)
    {
        $newPath = $this->getFilePath($path);
        $open = $this->archive->open($newPath, Archive::CREATE);
        if (true === $open) {
            if (!empty(basename($path))) {
                $this->archive->addFile($path, basename($path));
                return $this->archive->close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return new file path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return string
     */
    private function getFilePath($path)
    {
        $date = $this->timeZone->date()->format('Y-m-d-H:i:s');
        return $path . '-' . $date . '.zip';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__construct` method in your parent class declare `directoryList` as a required argument, so you need to declare `directoryList` argument in `__construct` method in your class.

To resolve your issue, open the parent class's file to check `__construct` method in the parent class.

Assume `__construct` method in the parent class has the following code:

```
public function __construct(
    DirectoryList $directoryList,
    Processor $processor,
    Archive $archive,
    TimezoneInterface $timezone
) {
//....
}
```

Your `__construct` method in your class should look like the following:

```
public function __construct(
    DirectoryList $directoryList,
    Processor $processor,
    Archive $archive,
    TimezoneInterface $timezone
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $directoryList,
        $processor,
        $archive,
        $timezone
    );
    $this->processor = $processor;
    $this->archive = $archive;
    $this->timeZone = $timezone;
}
```

Note: `DirectoryList` was imported by `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList`:
`use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;`

Comment: Thank you. that makes perfect sense. So add the USE up top with the rest and include the variable $directorylist in the public function construct and parent.

Comment: Glad to help @Singleton

Comment: quick question.. after i fixed that i tried to di:compile and apparently i'm running into another issue.. if you have time can you give me your thoughts on this one too.  Interception cache generation... 6/9 [==================>----]  66% 1 min 596.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
 Perficient\ImportExport\Model\Job\Handler\CompressHandler
  Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Job\Processor. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList; File: 
/home/tim/Integration2/psav/app/code/Perficient/ImportExport/Model/Job/Handler/CompressHandler.php

Comment: Please add the full content of your parent class file and your class file (CompressHandler) into your question.

Comment: Okay added the full CompressHandler.php file. Which other file are you looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141592/discussion-between-tu-van-and-singleton).

Comment: Singleton forgot to change the sort order of `__construct()` arguments, moving `$directoryList` argument to the last to the same as the parent method resolved the issue.